# I want error message for same purchase entry in Apex application

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using oracle 11g(Apex) in that I have created one report for purchases. It contains the purchase entries (we want to enter the purchase details of books) and for second time if I am entering the same books it should give error like `'Are you mean this purchase is already entered'`

```
Ex:
Book name - Rama
Book name - Sita
cash memo no - 01 (This purchase is already entered)

Book name - Rama
Book name - Sita
cash memo no - 02 (When i am entering this purchase it should ask are you mean the purchase of bill no 01)
```

For checking cash memo no and book name I have used the following validation in report but its not working properly.

Books i used as item name and cash memo no is like bill

```
declare
    cnt_sameitem number;
    cnt number;
begin
    select count(a.item_name),count(p.cash_memo_no) into cnt_sameitem,cnt     
    from T_TEMP_LINE_ITEM_P_ACT a,T_TOTAL_PURCHASES p 
    where a.purchase_id=:P55_PURCHASE_ID and 
          CODE=:P55_ITEM_CODE and a.ITEM_NAME=:P55_ITEM_NAME and             
          a.SELLING_PRICE=:P55_SELLING_PRICE;
    if (cnt_sameitem >=1) and (cnt >= 1)  then
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your validation for editing and enter your text `Are you mean this purchase is already entered` into the field `Error Message`. Also, you can select place to show error message (field `Error message display location`) - it can be displayed on an separate error page, or in a "notification" area (defined as part of the page template), or within the field label.